# Android Studios can't find SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, ascii, appdata

I have a problem where my Android Studios can't open my SDK. It says: `Your SDK loaction contains non-ASCII chracters.`

I have tried reinstalling everything twice, still not working.

Error Message:

http://postimg.org/image/a50xwsstb/7bd620d3/

SDK Location:

http://postimg.org/image/v0a1kul7b/

IT finds my JDK location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This character is not an ASCII character >> "é". Looks like the IDE doesn't support paths with non-ASCII characters in them.

Can't you place the SDK somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally!

Answer (score 0):

It is because your path has the letter e with accent in the word Andre. The path only accepts UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Use only words in English alphabet. Some characters are not supported.

and remember that you can change the `SDK` location.